# onmouseover just on the non-transparent part of the image

Tags: hover, transparency, imagemap, overlapping

I'm stuck with the menu below. All the website needs to be in HTML.

http://hpics.li/740c57f

**WHAT**: I want to have an hover image for all the different parts when the mouse go on it. (event/brand/website/print/UI/VIDEO)

**PROBLEM**: The images are overlapping and the mouseover start when i'm on the transparency of the png.

**SOLUTIONS I TRIED**: Imagemap to detect the zone and then put javascript code inside the AREA. doesn't work.
Imagemap to detect the zone, put an id in the AREA and use a separated JQUERY with .hover(function(). doesn't work.
Use z-index: impossible because there will be always an image that will hide the one under.

**QUESTION**: If I can't use ImapeMAP to select my zone and use CSS or JQUERY, how can I do ?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late but the exact case can actually be solved by a class I wrote around 3 months ago. It allows you to check whether you're on a transparent area or not and also check for other elements behind the transparent area, this allows to overlap multiple transparent images and correctly jump from one image to another at the correct point.

http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/pixelselection/